# Where can I find a C or C++ implementation of converting bitcoin privatekey to bitcoin public key and bitcoin address?

Tags: private-key, public-key, address-generation

There are versions in python and some such things, but I need a C version (or at least C++).
I do have the sha256, RMD160 in C already, and those functions are called. Thank you.

Comment: Well, there's always bitcoin-core... what do you need that you couldn't find there?

Comment: I would also suggest to look in the [SX](https://github.com/spesmilo/sx) source code.